# Visual studio 2019 console application .net 5 doen't recognice "My" services

Tags: vb.net, console, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I'm working with Visual Studio 16.9.1, and when I create a console application targeting .NET 5.0 (visual basic) I'm not able to access de "My." services (My.Appliation, My.Computer, My.User, ...). If I try to access the "My.Computer", for instance, I get the following error:

"BC30456: 'Computer' is not a member of 'Console1.My'"

What is very strange for me is that, if I create a Windows Forms App targeting the same .NET 5.0 it works OK, even if I create a console application targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2 it also works OK.

Am I missing something? Do I have to add some kind of reference?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: Missing `Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices`

Comment: I mean, that's imported from `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Forms.dll` in .Net 5.0, not `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`

Comment: Microsoft still have some work to do to get all the VB features they want supported in .NET Core. Whether or not the full `My` namespace is going to be supported in Console apps, I don't know, but it isn't at the moment. You're not missing something. It's just not there. There are almost certainly alternatives available though. I never near C# developers complaining that they have no `My` namespace.

Comment: Hello Jimi, do you mean that "My" is not available in .NET 5.0 console applications? Or do you mean that I must add/import a missing library? If it's the second option, any help about how to do it? I've been looking at dependencies and project references but I haven't been able to solve it.

Comment: A WinForms app is meant to run in Windows, either using .Net 5 or .Net Framework. So, the `My` services make sense there. A Console app is meant to run cross-platform. `My` services don't make sense there at this time, those are tools that, for a good part, are tied to Windows only (Shell, COM etc.). You'll have to decide what can be ported and what not, i.e., create a sub-set of the `My` implementations. Does it make sense? You can call .Net methods that map to those you mean to use (if/when available). Or use .Net Framework, if Windows-only is not a concern.